# Image copied to clipboard is cropped when pasted

Tags: ios, image, swift, ios9

I'm building a keyboard extension in Swift (Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 9.0.2). Since images cannot be directly inserted into the text field, I'm using UIPasteboard to copy the image from the app and then the user would paste manually into the text field. I have already modified info.plist to give the app full permission. I initially tried

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = UIImage(named: "1.png")
```

but I would receive the error

```
changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

I wasn't able to find anything to fix this error and nothing would be pasted into the clipboard. I then tried

```
let image = UIImage(named: "1.png")
let data = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!)
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data, forPasteboardType: "public.png")
```

This works perfectly for larger images, but smaller images are cropped on the right side.

1) Is there a way to programmatically resize the image as a UIImage before I send it to NSData?

2) Has anyone else experienced this issue or know why it's occurring? I'd ideally like the photos being pasted to be small but this is obviously problematic.

Thanks.

Comment: Getting same problem have you got any solution?

Comment: Never got a solution @kb920

Comment: Have you tried dumping the `NSData` before and after, to see if it is changed?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a proper solution, but adding some transparent padding to the right edge of the image is an effective workaround.